# Disable GPS time synchronization

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, gps, time-zones, date-and-time

I live in *Kiev, Ukraine*. My device is *Motorola Defy* with CyanogenMod 7 (2.3.7). In time settings there's no Ukraine timezone so I use *Minsk, Belarus* timezone (GMT +3). After I locate my position using GPS my phone's timezone changes to *African* (GMT +2).

Is there any way to disable GPS time synchronization on android?

*My phone is rooted.*

Comment: I cannot verify (as I'm not having this problem), but you might try setting the time to "manual" (uncheck the "auto" option in *settings->time & date*), and use e.g. [ClockSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.org.amip.ClockSync) for time syncing. for that app there's even a specific [TimeZoneDB for ClockSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.org.amip.timezoneservice) for -- as the dev puts it -- "Soviet Russia". And please let us know whether this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Android does not synchronize neither time nor time zone with GPS (I don't know about CyanogenMod but I don't think it works in some other way).

Android does synchronize both time and time zone with cellular network. I guess that your cellular network sends to you wrong time zone (African). You can disable it by unchecking "Automatic time zone" in Settings -> Date & time.